# Building Frames for Images w/ PhotoEditorSDK

Tags: ios, swift, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to create custom frames around my images (using Swift) using the photoeditor sdk. I am confused on their documentation and wanted some more insight if anyone has any.

According to the documentation - https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/ios/v8/features/frames - it looks as though I need to have 6 separate png files to create my frame (a top one, top left, top right, bottom, bottom left, bottom right). Is this right? If so, how would I create the corner images that constitute the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago. You do need to create separate png files for the top left right and bottom portions of the frame if that's how many sides of it there are. If there are only two sides to you frame, then uploading the `url` for left and right would still work since image groups, per the docs, are optionals.